# JavaScript - Alert all values of a array

Tags: javascript

I made this loop:

```
var intt =number;
var divider=[intt];
var i;
var count=0;
var b;
var temp=0;
var temp2=0;

for(i=1; i<=intt; i++){

    if(number%i==0){
        divider[count]=i;
        b=count++;

    }       
}
```

I was wondering, how do I put all the values of `divider` in an `alert()`?

Comment: `alert(divider)`? The array will be joined under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you like:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(divider));
```

or, you can [`join`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) all values into one string as following:

```
alert(divider.join(", "));
```

and then add it after your code like this:

```
var intt =number;
var divider=[intt];
var i;
var count=0;
var b;
var temp=0;
var temp2=0;

for(i=1; i<=intt; i++){

    if(number%i==0){
        divider[count]=i;
        b=count++;

    }       
}

alert(divider.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
    var intt =number;
    var divider=[intt];
    var i;
    var count=0;
    var b;
    var temp=0;
    var temp2=0;

    var strBldr = "";

    for(i=1; i<=intt; i++){

        if(number%i==0){
            strBldr = "".join(i+", ");
            divider[count]=i;
            b=count++;

        }       
    }

    strBldr = strBldr.slice(0, -2);
    alert(strBldr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness :)